# What is the easiest way to turn a LinkedList class into a Circular Linked List class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, linked-list

I have a LinkedList class that has close to 200 lines of code. I would like to make a new `class LLCircular(LinkedList)` by always making sure that any `myLL.tail.next is myLL.head`. I believe I would need to update `append()`, `push()`, `remove()`, etc. accordingly. Is there a way I can do this to keep the original LinkedList class intact? Maybe a decorator or some dunder method?

For brevity's sake, if reading the code, my `push()` method is just the inverse of `append()`. I also have a `pop()` and `remove()` method, which would need to be updated, if I just rewrite those methods. As I am trying to avoid that approach, I am not posting that part of the code.

```
class LinkedListNode:
   def __init__(self, value, nextNode=None, prevNode=None):
      self.value  = value
      self.next   = nextNode
      self.prev   = prevNode
   def __str__(self):
      return str(self.value)

class LinkedList:
   def __init__(self, values=None):
      self.head   = None
      self.tail   = None
      if values is not None:
         self.append(values)
   def __str__(self):
      values = [str(x) for x in self]
      return ' -> '.join(values)
   def append(self, value=None):
      if value is None:
         raise ValueError('ERROR: LinkedList.py: append() `value` PARAMETER MISSING')
      if isinstance(value, list):
         for v in value:
            self.append(v)
         return
      elif self.head is None:
         self.head   = LinkedListNode(value)
         self.tail   = self.head
      else:
         ''' We have existing nodes  '''
         ''' Head.next is same '''
         ''' Tail is new node '''
         self.tail.next = LinkedListNode(value, None, self.tail)
         self.tail      = self.tail.next
         if self.head.next is None:
            self.head.next = self.tail.prev
      return self.tail

'''class LLCircular(LinkedList):'''
    ''' ??? '''
```

Test Code:

```
foo = LinkedList([1,2,3])
foo.tail.next = foo.head #My LL is now circular
cur = foo.head
i = 0
while cur:
   print(cur)
   cur = cur.next
   i +=1
   if i>9:
      break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is to call your `LinkedList` base class functions using the `super` keyword, and then add the slight modifications to the `LLCircular` class function, i.e:

```
class LLCircular(LinkedList):
    def append(self, value=None):
        super(LLCircular, self).append(value)
        # In addition to having called the LinkedList append, now you want
        # to make sure the tail is pointing at the head
        self.tail.next = self.head
        self.head.prev = self.tail
```

Comment: I have been doing Android/Java Development for about 4 months now, and I am appalled I didn't think of this earlier ::joy:: Thank you!

Comment: `__init__` doesn't need to be overriden if all it does is call `__init__` higher up the chain.

Comment: Should no tit set `self.head.prev` to the new tail as well?

Comment: @T.Woody yeah it depends if your list is supposed to be 'double linked' or not, if your only traversing in one direction it would not be needed.

Comment: Note that the only reason you might need to update `self.tail.next` or `self.head.prev` is in the case of adding a node to an empty list; nothing about `LinkedList.append` would break an existing circular linked list. Using an appropriate "dummy" node in the implementation so that even an "empty" list contains something can get rid of even that special case.

Comment: You certainly will not "waste memory" by making it consistent - a reference to None has the same "memory cost" as a reference to the last item on the list.

Comment: but maybe, then, you don't need any of the `.prev` references - you r node could just have a `next` pointer, since you are only going forwrd on the list anyway. The memory saving with that is neglible, however, the code can be a lot simpler and less error prone.

Answer (score 1):

If it is "circular" it won't need a tail or head, would it? 
Nor "append" makes sense - insert_after and insert_before methods should be enough - also, any node is a reference to the complete circular list, no need for different objects:

```
class Circular:
    def __init__(self, value=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = self
        self.previous = self
    def insert_after(self, value):
        node = Circular(value)
        node.next = self.next
        node.previous = self
        self.next.previous = node
        self.next = node
    def insert_before(self, value):
        node = Circular(value)
        node.next = self
        node.previous = self.previous
        self.previous.next = node
        self.previous = node
    def del_next(self):
        self.next = self.next.next
        self.next.previous = self
    def __iter__(self):
        cursor = self.next
        yield self
        while cursor != self:
             yield cursor
             cursor = cursor.next
    def __len__(self):
        return sum(1 for _ in self)
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer; Thank you. I should have been more specific on wanting to make this a circular list with the existing LinkedList class, to avoid writing a new class in its entirety.

Comment: you might upvote this, if you liked it, and keep the other as accepted.